# What is the difference between memo writing and business letter writing?

Tags: business-writing

What is the difference between memo writing and business letter writing? Memo and business letters both are informal reports, so what is the main difference?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Hajra*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I think the problem is in your given. I would not define a *business letter* as an "informal report." A business letter is a letter you write to someone with whom you are, or may be, doing business, or possibly have done business with. It could be an invitation, a cover letter, a summary of a meeting, a threat, a request for information, a confirmation or rejection of a deal, etc. Only one of those could be considered an "informal report."

Answer (score 2):

A business letter is written to someone outside your company. Letters in general and business letter especially follow certain national (or international) conventions and norms. For example, the formatting and placement of dates and addresses may be prescribed by industry standards and the form of address follows social conventions. Besides these culture specific norms and conventions, most companies have style guides that require their employees to use certain formats when they communicate outside the company. For example, often there is a company letter paper, with the company logo in a specific color, size, and placement.

A memo(randum) on the other hand is a document that records events or decisions and is used internally, within the company. A company may or may not have a certain formatting requirement for a memorandum. Most distinctly, unlike the letter, it is usually not addressed to someone specific.